# Angular 2: How to add a class based on resolution condition?

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, resolution

I am building a responsive website, where I got a navigation button and side bar navigation.

If click it i would like to add a class based X resolution class A and based on Y resolution add a class B.

Or based on in what resolution the page is loaded to add a class or remove a class.

Comment: Are you referring to style classes? Or component classes? Do you have any code so far that you could post so we can better understand?

Comment: I am referring to CSS classes.  So based on resolution 776px I would like to add a class to an html attribute.

Comment: Have you seen ngClass? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use [flex/layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

For example,

```
<div [ngStyle.xs]="{'font-size.px': 10, color: 'blue'}"></div>
```

It adds "{'font-size.px': 10, color: 'blue'}" to style if screen size is small (xs)

Comment: instead of inline CSS, I would like to add a class that has all the styling.

Comment: it works with classess, too. use ngClass.xs instead of ngstyle. see https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API

Answer (score 0):

> Or based on in what resolution the page is loaded to add a class or remove a class.

That sounds like media queries, which are really outside of Angular entirely.

In your Angular styleUrl, specify a sheet that has the appropriate media queries for your component.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

If you're talking about dynamically applying classes based on some condition, look into `NgClass`.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[mq]'
})
class MediaQueryDirective {
  constructor(private zone:NgZone){}

  @HostBinding('class')
  classes:String;

  @Output()
  match = new EventEmitter();

  _mqReg = [];
  @Input() 
  set queries(value:any) {
    // unregister listeners from previous queries (not tested)
    if(this._mqReg.length) {
      this._mqReg.forEach(reg => reg.mq.removeListener(rer.handler));
      this._mqReg = [];
    }
    if(!value) {
      return;
    }
    // register listeners
    value.forEach((q) => {
      var mq = window.matchMedia(q.query);
      var handler = (e) => this.matches(e, q);
      this._mqReg.push({mq: mq.addListener(handler), handler: handler});
      console.log('mq', mq);
      // set the initial value - see also comment on queries in App
      if(mq.matches) {
        this.matches(null, q);
      }
    });
  }

  // on query match get class from query and set it on the host component
  matches(e, q) {
    console.log('matches', e);
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.match.emit(q);
      this.classes = q.class;
    });
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/e5xqgFcMYMkGNMbjEWlT)

Comment: Great stuff, but how would you add a specific class instead of adding a media query class and than adding css to it.

Comment: The CSS class to add if a query matches is passed with the `quieries` (in `App` component) using the `class` field. Not sure if this is what your question is about.

Comment: I would like to add a class for the menu when the viewport is mobile or the resolution is on mobile, so the menu can behave differently.

Comment: I still don't get it. I think this is exactly what my directive is about. `@HostBinding('class')` adds a class to the element where the directive is added to, when a mediaquery matches.